# how to extract the number of google hits for many term continuously?

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to use the Class of HttpClient to extract the number of google hits for many terms continuously,but the google server don't let me to do this operation repeately,can you help me? here is my program ,the parameter Concept is the term I want to search。

```
public static double extractGoogleCount(String Concept)
    {
    double temp = 0;
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&newwindow=1&q="
        + Concept + "&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=";
    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
    getMethod.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
        new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler());
    try
    {
        int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            System.err.println("Method failed: "
                + getMethod.getStatusLine() + url);
        }
        InputStream responseBody = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(responseBody);
        String returnPage = dis.readLine();
        while (returnPage != null)
        {
            int index = returnPage.indexOf("<div id=\"resultStats\">");
            if (index == -1)
            {
            returnPage = dis.readLine();
            continue;
            }
            String sub = returnPage.substring(index, index + 100);
            if (sub.indexOf("About") >= 0)
            {

            String[] result = sub.split(" ");
            String number = result[2].replaceAll(",", "");
            temp = Double.parseDouble(number);
            } else
            {
            String[] result = sub.split(" ");
            String number = result[1].substring(result[1]
                .indexOf(">") + 1);
            System.out.println("number:" + number);
            temp = Double.parseDouble(number);
            }
            break;
        }

        return temp;
    } catch (HttpException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Please check your provided http address!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return temp;
    } finally
    {
        httpClient.getState().clear();
        getMethod.releaseConnection();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Woah! Hold up. Can you indent the code properly so it shows as code please. It hurts my eyes

Answer (score 0):

Google only allows a certain number of requests per second from a single client.
Try adding:

```
 Thread.sleep(200);
```

To the code and it should work. You might want to create another thread to do the getting work so you can do other stuff with your program if you need to display this data somehow

Comment: I'm so glad you answer my question. However,I'm so sorry because "Thread.sleep(200)" doesn't work when the number of terms is large(i want to Google about thousands of terms).So, i want to know whether or not I can use proxy in my program?

Comment: First, which API are you using?

Comment: I'm using the HttpClient , here is its introduction:http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html